# Subscriptions was added in the Youtube AP's Activities: list recently?

Tags: api, youtube

I use this function (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) to retrieve list of user activities.

I use my `channelId` and I don't see subscriptions for period before autumn of 2021. Can anyone explain me why? May be you write me when this type of activity (subscription) was added in the type of request, named Activities: list?

Thanks!

See below example code:

```py
import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.activities().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails",
        channelId="yourChannelId", #Note: paste your own channelId
        maxResults=300
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can do an example of request in the right side:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried with `mine=true` instead of using your `channelId`?

Comment: Yes, i tried to use mine=True instead specifying channelId, but i've got the same result. I see only uploads. Whereas i see my subscriptions only after autumn of 2021.


Also, I change publishedBefore parameter, and get the same result...

So, i assume subscription recordings store since recently time. Who knows since what day? :D